# Make sure that data is loaded before the application startup | Spring webflux

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a spring webflux application.

I am loading some list from database into bean. I have two ways of implementing the loading of this bean.

Approach 1: Reactive Way

```
@Bean
  public List<Item> getItemList() throws IOException {
     List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
     itemRespository.findAll().collectList().subscribe(itemList::addAll);
     return itemList;
  }
```

Approach 2 : Blocking way

```
@Bean
public List<Item> getItemList() throws IOException {
     List<Item> itemList = itemRespository.findAll().collectList().block();
     return itemList;
 }
```

Now as I want my application to be reactive, I don't want to use the blocking way.
But the endpoints which I am exposing through my controller depends on this bean's data.

```
@RestController
public class SomeController{

   @Autowired
   private List<items> getItemList;

   @GetMapping('/endpoint')
   public void process(){
     List list = getItemList; //this may not get initialzed as the bean loading is reactive

     //some more code
}
}
```

So in case of reactive approach, it may happen that somebody may call my endpoint(as application has already started and ready to serve requests), while due to some reason it may happened that my list has yet not bean retrieved from database(may be any reason ex: slowness of database server etc.), producing inconsistent results for the users calling my endpoint(which in turns depend on this bean).

I am looking for a solution for this scenario.

**EDIT** :  More precise question is that should I load those beans reactively in my application, on which my exposed endpoints are dependent?

Comment: `Now as I want my application to be reactive, I don't want to use the blocking way` makes no sense here. You want your application to work. If you need the items to be in place before you the first call with your design, you need to block. Another aproach would be instead to fetch the data on the first call to your api and store the data in a cache after the first call so that the subsequent calls go to the cache.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I agree

Comment: @Toerktumlare But don't you think this way, my Main thread will be blocked and it may happen that it may eat up the memory in case of any subtle issue(slowness or timeout), when it would have done some other work?

Comment: Yes, your application may be slow to start up, but thats the way you have designed it. You cant fetch items that dont exist! You need to block until they are avaliable. You have designed your application in that way that it has to block. Thats why i suggested a different design.

Comment: I like your suggestion about cache, do we have a stable implementation that can be used along with Reactive spring webflux, or any code example or Document/article online? @Toerktumlare

Comment: `we` dont have anything. I answer questions on stack overflow on my spare time. Stack overflow is not a forum, a discord or a development team. I have answerted your question. Good luck

Comment: No No, I was asking for some open source solution available online for cacheswith spring webflux. Anyway, thanks for the assistance you provided. It really helped me to develop a point of view for the problem statement, I really appreciate you for sharing your knowledge with me. I will dig more by myself :) @Toerktumlare

Comment: I wouldn't call approach 1 reactive. Why does the method not return a Flux?

Answer (score 1):

The current application architecture solution presented is a typical example on a design that is inherently blocking.

If the first request made to the api *needs* the items to be in place, then we must sure that they are there before we can take on requests. And the only way to ensure that is to `block` until the items de facto have been fetched and stored.

Since the design is inherently blocking, we need to rethink our approach.

What we want is to make the service available for requests as quick as possible. We can solve this by using a cache, that will get filled when the first request is made.

Which means application starts up with an empty cache. This cache could for instance be a `@Component` as spring beans are singletons by default.

the steps would be:

- service starts up, cache is empty
- service receives its first request
- checks if there is data in the cache
- if data is stale, evict the cache
- if cache is empty, fetch the data from our source
- fill the cache with our fetched data
- set a ttl (time to live) on the data placed in the cache
- return the data to the calling client

Second request:

- request comes in to the service
- checks if there is data in the cache
- checks if the data is stale
- if not grab the data and return it to the calling subscriber

There are several cache solutions out there, spring has their `@Cachable` [annotation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/), which by default is just a key value store, but can be paired with an external solution like redis etc.

Other solutions can be `Google guava` which has a very good [read](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained) on their github.

This type of solution is called *trading memory for cpu* we gain startup time and fast requests (cpu), but the cost is we will spend some more memory to hold data in a cache.

Comment: Thanks :), I will try these steps.

Comment: please accept the answer if it helped you so others can find it in the future

Comment: The actual story is, this data list 'L1' loaded from database at app start up  will be used, when say some 'calculate( )' end point will be called, That end point will send some response, and one of the field of the response is going to set its value on that preloaded list 'L1'.  If I use cache for that preloaded data(L1), then my call will be like, load that list if not available in cache -> that needs to be blocking -> then run the actual code ->  which actually fetch domain object from db -> create a response from both and send back to client. More precisely, we have to chain the DB calls.